# How to mock OAuth2 token introspect using Spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I have a spring-boot Webflux application and I am writing some tests using Spock and Groovy.

My Controllers are secured with OAuth opaque token which I need to mock a response from introspection.
My test properties are:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id=fake_client
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret=fake_secret
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri=http://localhost:8089/api/v1/oauth/token/introspect
```

My test uses `WebClient` as below:

```java
webClient.post()
    .uri(URL.toString()))
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .headers(http -> http.setBearerAuth("bearer_token"))
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .is2xxSuccessful()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between Spock and JUnit when mocking spring security-context. You can provide with mocked `Authentication` for both unit (`@WebFluxTest`) and integration (`@SpringBootTest`) with either:

- `org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers.mockOpaqueToken` mutator for WebTestClient
- `@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication` annotation.

Mocked `BearerTokenAuthentication`, Spring's auth implementation for token introspection (unless you explicitly changed it in your conf), is put in test security-context directly by annotation or mutator: authorization header is not introspected (it is completely ignored and can be omitted).

Sample (with JUnit, just adapt to your test framework) in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webflux-introspecting-default):

```java
@Test
void securedRouteWithAuthorizedPersonnelViaMutatorIsOk() throws Exception {
    api
        .mutateWith(mockOpaqueToken()
            .attributes(attributes -> attributes.put(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME, "Ch4mpy"))
            .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")))
        .get().uri("https://localhost/secured-route")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk();
}

@Test
@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication(
    authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL",
    attributes = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Ch4mpy"))
void securedRouteWithAuthorizedPersonnelViaAnnotationIsOk() throws Exception {
    api
        .get().uri("https://localhost/secured-route")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk();
}
```

When testing other secured `@Component` type than `@Controller` (like `@Service` or `@Repository`), only test annotation is usable as there is no HTTP request:

```java
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, SecretRepo.class })
class SecretRepoTest {
    // auto-wire tested component
    @Autowired
    SecretRepo secretRepo;

    @Test
    void whenNotAuthenticatedThenThrows() {
        // call tested components methods directly (do not use MockMvc nor
        // WebTestClient)
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> secretRepo.findSecretByUsername("ch4mpy").block());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication(attributes = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenAuthenticatedAsSomeoneElseThenThrows() {
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> secretRepo.findSecretByUsername("ch4mpy").block());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication(attributes = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "ch4mpy"))
    void whenAuthenticatedWithSameUsernameThenReturns() {
        assertEquals("Don't ever tell it", secretRepo.findSecretByUsername("ch4mpy").block());
    }
}
```

Annotation is available from

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-oauth2-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which is a transient dependency of

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-introspecting-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I used the later in sample to also have `WebTestClientSupport`, but first is enough for just test annotations.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I don't think it will work for me. I need information "hidden" in the opaque token later in the code.

Comment: Yes, it does work. The information associated to the token is not "hidden" anymore after token introspection, which happens before `BearerTokenAuthentication` is build and put in security context.

Comment: @DariuszUrbanek see my updated answer: how do you plan to test a secured `@Component` that is not a `@Controller`? Also please, be curious enough to try the proposed solution and also to inspect, from within a controller or service at runtime (with a real token introspection), the content of `((BearerTokenAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).getTokenAttributes()`: you should see the information is not hidden in there.

Comment: For some reason I am having problems with your dependency:
 `Could not resolve com.c4-soft.springaddons:spring-addons-oauth2-test:6.0.3`
Also, Your test works with annotated @Test - what about Spock and Groovy? Will it be applicable? I am keen to try it anyway, but will probably have to park it for now.

Comment: You might have a typo or issue to access maven-central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/c4-soft/springaddons/spring-addons-oauth2-test/6.0.3/ And yes, as already wrote, annotation should work the same with Spock + Groovy as it does with the samples @Test linked (written with JUnit +Java)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You have to configure WireMockServer and then stub the response. Working solution below:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class SomeTest extends Specification {

  private static final int PORT = 8089;

  private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

  def setup() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(PORT))
    wireMockServer.start()
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port())

  def stubIntrospection() {
    stubFor(post("/api/v1/oauth/token/introspect")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .withBodyFile("path-to-my-file.json")))
  }

  def "my test case" () {

    stubIntrospection()

    //my test here    
  }

  }
```

Comment: Consider how more verbose this is compared to test annotation exposed in my answer. Also this solution requires to maintain a separate json test resource for each and every user profile. Last, even if you are not directly impacted (for now), this is applicable for introspection only and not for JWT decoding: JWTs are signed with authorization-server private key, which makes it impossible to produce valid JWTs for wiremock.

Comment: Also, this won't work for tests that are neither `@SpringBootTest` nor `@WebFluxTest` like when unit-testing a secured `@Service` or `@Repository`